# How do I place stations in Ticket to Ride on Steam?

Tags: ticket-to-ride-europe

I'm playing Ticket to Ride, Europe, online using the Steam version on a Macintosh. I understand the rules of stations, just not how to physically place on the game board. For example:

[image]
In this map I'm attempting a route from Madrid to Wien. My opponent has blocked me from Müchen to Wien. You can see in the lower right hand corner that I have 3 stations available. If I click on my stations I get the same dialog that I get if I click my avatar, the one that shows routes complete, train cards, route cards, and trains. Curiously, it does not list stations. I've tried all the modifiers, control, command, option, shift click etc...

I cannot drag to the made route, I cannot click on the cities where I want the stations. How do I place a station in the online version?

Comment: this will probably be closed as not in scope of boardgames.stackexchange.com.  however have you tried dragging a card to the city?  That's what you do in the iOS app.  You said you tried dragging to the route and clicking on a city  but not dragging wagon cards to a city.

Comment: That's it. Quick, add that as a answer and I'll you some points.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is asking for instructions on how to use the controls of a computer based version of a board game.

Comment: "Questions about computer implementations of board games are fine." -- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @StartPlayer : you should definitely add your answer as an answer, since this is indeed on-topic for bg.se.com

Comment: I've reopened, because the close reason that was used here says "except for computer-based versions of board or card games." Deeming this type of question off-topic would be a policy change; please post on [meta] if you want to discuss that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case StartPlayer doesn't put in an answer. Once he does I'll mark his as correct.

> Have you tried dragging a card to the city? That's what you do in the
>   iOS app. You said you tried dragging to the route and clicking on a
>   city but not dragging wagon cards to a city.
>
> StartPlayer

Comment: ... and until then you can mark this one as correct. (You can change your "correct" designation later when / if StartPlayer answers.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take any card and move it to a specific station that you would like to claim. And that is it.